# Problems installing Numpy in Virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, numpy

I have `numpy` installed globally (I think via Django) but I'm trying to install it within a virtualenv. When I run

```
pip install numpy
```

(within my virtualenv), it gets stuck at `Running setup.py install for numpy`.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? If you require any additional information just let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: Do you have gcc installed? run the command `gcc -v`!

Comment: This issue has been resolved in pip version 8.

Answer (score 2):

Googling it comes mainly to specific solution taking about presence of gcc and other packages.

Check if gcc is installed else install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Also you need to install those packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```